# Cancelled upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04, refusing to upgrade again

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, upgrade, updates

When I was updating from 11.10, to 12.04, I cancelled because the computer froze. Now the update manager doesn't show an upgrade option. How do I upgrade? It said I could continue through a location I cannot remember. And it downloaded some files already. is their some command-line thingy or a location to continue the process?

Answer (score 1):

You can continue the upgrade by running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in a terminal.

Comment: I tried. However, it said command not found

Comment: Which command is not found?

Comment: The whole one you just gave me.

Comment: Is it saying dpkg is not found? Or sudo?

Comment: it's saying sudo and dpkg arn't found

Comment: Then, run su then apt-get install dpkg.

Comment: @William: Don't type the single quotes. Just run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Don't use `su`--that won't work, because [root has no password set](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). @whiskers75: You can use code highlighting in your posts to make clear what's part of a command and what's not.